# In sockets, why do I have to use sizeof(addr) in connect() instead of using (socklen_t)&addr like in accept()?

Tags: c++, sockets, sizeof, socklen-t

I'm experimenting with sockets in C++, and I don't understand why in the `accept()` function the last parameter is:

```
socklen_t *addr_len
```

And I can do this:

```
accept(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addr);
```

But in the `connect()` function the last parameter is:

```
socklen_t addr_len
```

And i get an error when I do this:

```
connect(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t)&addr);
```

> error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'socklen_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information

In that second case, why do I have to use `sizeof(addr)` instead of `(socklen_t)&addr`?

Comment: The call `accept(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addr);` writes the size into `addr`. `connect(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t)addr);` reads the value. The former is call by reference and the latter is call by value. `accept(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addr);` contains a typo and should be `accept(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addr_len);`

Comment: You can read it [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html)

Comment: Just because the compiler doesn't complain about the `accept()` call doesn't mean it's correct. On entry, the last parameter should be the address of a `socklen_t` variable that has been set to the length of the buffer whose address is passed in as the second parameter, and on return will be set to the _actual_ length of the address structure written to the address passed in the second parameter. Using `&addr` for both parameters is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter of `accept()` is an **input/output** parameter passed *by pointer*. The caller needs to pass in the *address* of an allocated `sockaddr_...` buffer in the 2nd parameter, and pass in the *address* of a `socklen_t` variable in the 3rd parameter, where that variable specifies the buffer's allocated size.  The function will copy the accepted peer's information into the caller's `sockaddr_...` buffer, being sure not to exceed the specified buffer size.  The number of bytes copied to the buffer will be **written back to the `socklen_t` variable** upon exit.

```cpp
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(addr);
accept(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len);
```

The last parameter of `connect()` is an **input-only** parameter passed *by value*.  The caller needs to pass in the *address* of an allocated and populated `sockaddr_...` buffer in the 2nd parameter, and pass in the *value* of the buffer's populated size in the 3rd parameter.  The function will read from the caller's `sockaddr_...` buffer, being sure not to exceed the specified buffer size. The function does not write anything back to the caller, so no `socklen_t` variable is needed (but you can use one if you want to).

```
connect(m_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```